# On "click" button trigger some CSS values instead of "hover" using Tailwind and React

Tags: css, reactjs, user-interface, frontend, tailwind-css

I want to form some kind of event trigger that would display Tailwind values only during when my click is pressed. If I keep on pressing the button would appear as if it is physically pressed i.e. "shadow-inner" or some other tailwind value

Do I need a separate event listener or is there some tailwind event like "hover:" that I don't know of

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what “when my click is pressed” means? Is this for touch devices or a mouse or… Thanks.

Comment: Explain more on what issue you are actually facing

Comment: i want some tailwind effect to trigger only when i'm holding down mouse click on a button for instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `active:` variant which represents `:active` [pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active).

> The :active CSS pseudo-class represents an element (such as a button) that is being activated by the user. When using a mouse, "activation" typically starts when the user presses down the primary mouse button.

```html
<button type="button" class="bg-red-500 active:bg-blue-500">Button</button>
```

This button will be blue when clicked (pressed)

[DEMO](https://play.tailwindcss.com/sA2wiDIWv4)

Answer (score 0):

There is no events in tailwind for this, since this is JavaScript.

You have to use `mousedown` and `mouseup` to achieve what you want.

For example :

```
const button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
  // logic here
});

button.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
  // logic here
});
```

Comment: interesting, but i prefer Ihar-Aliakseyenka's answer without using event Listeners. Thanks anyways 